# How to select geography features within a certain distance given in miles?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I am just taking the first steps in using POSTGIS, but having trouble finding a simple example.

I have a database with a Key field, lat and lon fields and a GEOGRAPHY field.

I just want to have a query that gives me all of the Key fields with 100 miles of the following Lat/Lon 52.474702, -132.373041.

A pseudo query would be something like

```
select Key from GIS where GEOM is within 100 miles of 52.474702, -132.373041
```

Comment: Have a look at the answer to http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13082/promotion-radius-in-miles-around-venues-using-postgis?rq=1. Please note that it is good practice to use descriptive titles for your threads and include information about what you have tried so far in your question.

Comment: I looked at that example, but it doesn't use the GEOGRAPHY field. That's the problem I'm having I usually like to have a series of very small, tightly focused queries that show how to achieve simple tasks. This then leads to developing a greater understanding. With POSTGIS I keep finding examples, with lots of stuff, I don't, which hides the thing I am actually trying to achieve. So far I haven't tried anything with a level of understanding to know I am on the right lines.

Comment: So a psuedo query would be something like select Key from GIS where GEOM is within 100 miles of 52.474702, -132.373041

Comment: Please edit the question to add information, so that those who would answer don't have to sift through comments for critical details.

Answer (score 2):

Use [STDWithin](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) to check if the features are within the desired distance

> For geography units are in meters and measurement is defaulted to use_spheroid=true

The documentation page provides simple examples of the usage of this function. In your case this should work:

`SELECT key
FROM the_table
WHERE ST_DWithin(
   GEOM, 
   ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(-132.373041 52.474702)'),
   100 * 1609.344
)`